# EU consent form Admod / Flutter: error when requesting consent info update

Tags: flutter, admob, gdprconsentform

I am trying to use the GDPR EU consent form for Admob and Flutter [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent). The form is set up from my AdMob account.

There is an error when I use the first function of the docs:

```
final params = ConsentRequestParameters();
ConsentInformation.instance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
  params,
  () async {
    // The consent information state was updated.
    // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
  },
  (FormError error) {
    // Handle the error
  },
);
```

The error is:

- For IOS: "Unable to update publisher identifier info"
- For Android: "Failed to get ad id"

Please note that the IDFA alert set up from my AdMob account works.

My appID seems to be well set up in the Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my AdMob account was not approved. I requested the approval.

It is working now.